# How to create factory girl for same model with different foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot

I have a task model which has many users and task belongs to users. I can assign tasks to another users.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
has_many :tasks_assigned, foreign_key: "assigned_to_id", dependent: :destroy
```

**task.rb**

```
belongs_to :assigned_to , class_name: "User"  
belongs_to :user
```

I want to create a factorygirl for task with fields task name and assigned_to_id. I have done the following code

**factories/task.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :task_wop do |t|      
   t.task "test_task"
   t.assosciation :assigned_to
   t.assosciation :user
   t.association :project
end
end
```

I am using this in cucumber user steps as

```
Given /^I have a task without project$/ do
  @task_wop = FactoryGirl.create(:task_wop, project_id: nil)  
end
```

But I am getting the error as

```
 Attribute already defined: assosciation (FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError)
  ./features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:19:in `/^I have a task without project$/'
```

I need help to figure what the error is? and why is it occuring. Is it the correct way to define a factory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelled `association` the same way (`assosciation`) twice in your factory, so it thinks you're trying to define the same attribute twice.